# How to get complete proof in z3 using s.proof()?

Tags: z3, z3py

If proof is too long, s.proof() able to print only part of the. Is there any other function available using which we can get complete proof.

I am using following code

```
from z3 import *
set_param(proof=True)
.
.

.
.
if unsat==s.check():
     s.proof()
```

Please guide me.

Comment: `s.proof()` returns an instance of `ExprRef`, which apparently has a number of methods which allow for walking through its elements (organised in a tree). Thus, you could write your own print function for this object.

Comment: Thanks a lot ...It is working

Comment: If you wrote the code for doing it already, you should add an answer containing it and accept it as correct answer, so that it will help others in the future. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from z3 import *
set_param(proof=True)
.
.

.
.
if unsat==s.check():
     print s.proof().children()
```

Can print complete proof